# Rails associations confusing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have 4 models, which are `Company`, `Candidate`, `Job` and `Application`

For `Company`

```
has_many :candidates
has_many :jobs
```

For `Candidate`

```
belongs_to :company
has_one :application
```

For `Jobs`

```
belongs_to :company
has_many :applications
```

For `Application`

```
belongs_to :candidate
belongs_to :job
```

I'm not sure whether the relationships between `Candidate`, `Jobs` and `Application` are correct or not. It would be great if someone can give some suggestions for improvement. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Adding indirect assocations as well will let you query up and down the heirarchy:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :applications, through: :jobs
  has_many :candidates, through: :applications
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :applications
  has_many :candidates, through: :applications
end

class Application  < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :candidate
  belongs_to :job
  has_one :company, through: :job
end

class Candidate < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :applications
  has_many :jobs, through: :applications
  has_many :companies, through: :jobs
end
```

Comment: An additional tip is to write your examples as code or metacode. I have never got the point of writing the class name and the contents seperately as its much easier to follow if its properly indented.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to build activerecord associations is to imagine your associations in real life. In this case, a company has several jobs, each job has several applications, and each application has one candidate.

Hence the relation would be

for Company

```
has_many :jobs
```

for Job

```
belongs_to :company
has_many :applications
```

for Application

```
belongs_to :job
has_one :candidate
```

for Candidate

```
belongs_to :application
```

Comment: I would put Application `belongs_to :canditate` as that would let a candidate apply for more than one job. Which means the OP actually got it right.

Comment: And I would add for Comapny `has_many :applications, through: :jobs` and `has_many :candidates, through: :applications`